# Where can I find the file VisualSVNServerHooks.exe

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks, post-commit

I'm trying to activate the post-commit hook in SVN, and I don't have the file VisualSVNServerHooks.exe

where can I find it?

Thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is configured correctly, just use the full path in your hook script:

```
%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe"
```

where VISUALSVN_SERVER is the install location of VisualSVN, set up as a path variable.

---

VisualSVNServerHooks.exe should be installed with the rest of the install. I've just double checked it is included in the MSI install for version 2.0.2. Did you install the full version or just the management console?

Rerunning the MSI should allow you to modify the install to the full version, and you should get the exe when you do so.

Comment: I wrote that, and what do you mean by everything? I set up a Server and everything was configured correctly. The file just not exist.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded v 2.0.2 and the file exists.
everything works perfectly!!!

:-)

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to vote up or accept the answer as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've just checked my install - its located in c:\program files\VisualSVN Server\bin directory.

What version are you installing?